# Comparison in swich-case does not give the correct value

Tags: c, pointers, char

I am very new to programming with C. I am making a small program that calculates:

- Arithmetic mean (A)
- Geometric mean(G)
- Harmonic Mean (H)

the program receives some letter of the above that indicates which function is going to be executed and a list of floats with which it will work in said function:

```
float aritmetic(float datos[], int n)
float geometric(float datos[], int n)
float harmonic(float datos[], int n)
```

the main function is as follows:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = argc-2;

    float data[1];

    char operation = *argv[1];

    for(int j = 0;j < argc-2;j++){
        data[j] = atof(argv[j+2]);
    }

    switch(operation)
    {   
        case 'A':
            printf("%f\n",aritmetic(data,n));
        case 'G':
            printf("%f\n",geometric(data,n));
        case 'H':
            printf("%f\n",harmonic(data,n));
        default:
            return 0;
    }

}
```

But in the switch, it does not recognize any character, it always sends me to the default clause, could someone guide me to solve the problem?

Comment: Post the complete command line call to your program.  Replace `return 0;` with `printf("%d\n", operation); return 0;`.

Comment: Change `float data[1];`  to `float data[100];`. `float data[1];` only good if `argc <= 3`

Comment: `float data[1];` declares an array of 1 element. Unless `j` is 0, accessing `data[j]` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Just to point out; `argv[ 1 ]` is being used without bothering to check the value of `argc`... In some cases, `switch( NULL )` might cause some aggravation. In fact, Following the NULL pointer to assign the operator is bound to be calamitous...

Comment: Side note: You should generally have a `break` at the end of every switch case, unless you intentionally want the program to fall through to the next case.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I see that you commented with the core of my answer while I edited. Decent minds sometimes think alike.

Comment: Quick question: Do you type an UPPERCASE letter on the command line when trying to specify the "operation"?

Answer (score 4):

I created this minimal example to verify your description.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = argc-2;


    if(argc < 2) return 1;
    
    char operation = *argv[1];



    switch(operation)
    {   
        case 'A':
            printf("a\n");
            //break;
        case 'G':
            printf("g\n");
            //break;
        case 'H':
            printf("h\n");
            //break;
        default:
            return 0;
            //break;
    }
    
    return 2;

}
```

It turns out that the switch executes not only the default case, but all the cases, if the input starts with "A".
This is because you omitted the needed `break`s, which I inserted as comments.

In case this does not match your observation, the problem is likely caused by the undefined behaviour and lack of plausibility checking, as hinted in the comments.

Comment: Love the output of your stripped down version: "AAAGGGHHHH!!!" Just like Charlie Brown... `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues in the code:

- There is a typo in `float data[1];` you should define an array of length `n` instead.
- Furthermore, you should test the value of `argc` before this definition.
- There are missing `break;` statements after the `printf()` in each clause in the `switch` statement.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float arithmetic(float datos[], int n);
float geometric(float datos[], int n);
float harmonic(float datos[], int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("missing arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char operation = *argv[1];
    if (!operation || !strchr("AGH", operation)) {
        printf("invalid operation: %c, expect A, G or H\n", operation);
        return 1;
    }
    int n = argc - 2;
    float data[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char *p;
        data[i] = strtof(argv[i + 2], &p);
        if (p == argv[i + 2] || *p != '\0') {
            printf("invalid number: %s\n", argv[i + 2]);
        }
    }

    switch (operation) {   
      case 'A':
        printf("%f\n", arithmetic(data, n));
        break;
      case 'G':
        printf("%f\n", geometric(data, n));
        break;
      case 'H':
        printf("%f\n", harmonic(data, n));
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Fe2O3: fair point. Answer amended.

Comment: I just wanted to see "AGH"... It'd be better with a 'bang' or 3: "AGH!!!" :-)

Comment: Minor: `if (p == argv[i + 2]) {` a tad better as `if (p == argv[i + 2] || *p) {`

Answer (score 0):

In light of the issues pointed out in the comments above, and realising that a short list of numbers will be processed in the wink-of-an-eye:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    float data[ argc ]; // an unused float floating around
    memset( data, 0, sizeof data );

    for( int j = 1; j < argc; j++ )
        data[ j - 1 ] = atof( argv[ j ] );

    printf( "Arithmetic mean: %f\n", aritmetic( data, argc - 1 ) );
    printf( "Geometric mean: %f\n", geometric( data, argc - 1 ) );
    printf( "Harmonic mean: %f\n", harmonic( data, argc - 1 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** Forgive me for taking advantage of this question and trying to learn what the last two items actually are... (Thank you Wikipedia!)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if( argc < 2 ) return 1;

    float sum = 0.0;
    float sumrecip = 0.0;
    float prod = 1.0;

    int count = --argc;
    while( argc ) {
        float v = (float)atof( argv[ argc-- ] );
        sum += v;
        sumrecip += 1.0/v;
        prod *= v;
    }

    printf( "Arithmetic mean: %f\n", sum/count );
    printf( "Geometric mean: %f\n", (float) powf( prod, 1.0/count ) );
    printf( "Harmonic mean: %f\n", count/sumrecip );

    return 0;
}
```

for command `./a.out 1 4 4`

```
Arithmetic mean: 3.000000
Geometric mean: 2.519842
Harmonic mean: 2.000000
```

Sure 'nuff. Done in the *wink-of-an-eye*.
Life's lesson: Don't go looking for confusion. It'll find you.
(I do hope the math is right in this answer...)

Comment: `float data[ argc ] = { 0 };` is non standard: the C Standard does not mandate support for initializers in VLA definitions.

Comment: `(float)powf(...)` is redundant... the whole computation should use `double` anyway.

Comment: @chqrlie I've changed the initialisation (written theoretically because I use a compiler pre-dating VLA's.) Thanks. Casting because the OP used floats... (I didn't want to change ALL of the OP code...)

Comment: I understand your keeping `float`, but `powf()` returns a `float` so no need to cast as `(float)`. Note that the `float` will be implicitly converted to `double` when passed to a vararg function like `printf`, which also expects a `double` for `%f`. For consistency, you should either write `powf(prod, 1.0F/count)` or `pow(prod, 1.0/count)`

Comment: @chqrlie It's been a day... The casting does no harm where it is...

Comment: Casts are not *harmless*, they are bugs in a chrysalis.